# Elementary set-theory: partial orders

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question concerning partial orders:

$A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $X=\{B \subseteq A \mid 1 \in B \text{ or } 2 \in B\}$

1. Show that the relation $\subseteq$ on $X$ is a partial order.
2. Find all maximal, minimal, greatest and least elements.

To be honest, I feel completely lost from the beginning and don't really understand what the question is. I don't feel confident when it comes to questions like these and have really, really hard time getting a grasp of them.

Since $X = B \subseteq A$ I suppose that we know that $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$ since $B$ is a subset? 
As you see, I'm completely lost. I do know that a partial order is reflexive, transitive and anti-symmetric but don't really know what to of that when the question is phrased like this.

Comment: $X$ is the set of all subsets of $A$ which satisfy the particular property that they contain at least one of the elements $1$ or $2$.  $X$ should look similar to the power set of $\{1,2,3\}$ except it is missing some elements.  Lets start writing out the power set of $A$ and then remove the pieces that shouldn't be there.  $\{\color{red}{\emptyset},\{1\},\{2\},\color{red}{\{3\}},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$

Comment: Now... continuing the problem, you do indeed need to show that the partial order is reflexive, transitive, and anti-symmetric.  Suppose that $B\in X$.  That means that $B\subseteq A$ and $1\in B$ or $2\in B$.  Is it true that this implies that $B\subseteq B$?  Is a set a subset of itself?  How about transitivity, if we have $B\subseteq B'$ and $B'\subseteq B''$ where all three of $B,B',B''$ are elements of $X$, does this imply that $B\subseteq B''$?  Finally, anti-symmetry, I'll leave to you to remember what that should mean.

Comment: You've written $$X=B\subseteq A$$ and yet that's not what the problem says, instead the problem says $$X = \{B \subseteq A \, | \, 1 \in B \,\text{or}\, 2 \in B\}$$ Do you see and understand the difference?

Comment: Oh yeah, that's an unfortunate mistake and I do get the difference. 

I still don't get the question completely though but I'll look into it now with your explanations.